# NPM, Angular, and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, angular, macos, terminal

When I use the [Eclipse Angular](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse) 1.3.0 plugin, the CLI within Eclipse does not seem work as it doesn't recognize that I have NPM or Angular CLI installed.  For example, see the first screenshot from Eclipse for when I try to create a component in the IDE:

[image: Eclipse Angular Plugin CLI]

I get the error indicated in screenshot indicating the terminal cannot find the 'ng' command as if it's not on the path.  Also, trying to execute NPM within the terminal in Eclipse does nothing.  Both are on the path and work fine when running them in the native terminal:

[image: Terminal]

This is running on a Mac, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: There different Angular plug-ins. Which one do you use?

Comment: It is the Angular Eclipse 1.3.0 plugin - https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site.

Comment: Please try with 1.4.0 SNAPSHOT https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site